# how to convert Date in to Feb 26, 2016 in java

Tags: java, android

i have date format in  02/20/2016  i have to convert it in to Feb 26, 2016 please suggest me how to convert it in this format .

Comment: Check out documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: can u suggest me which format i have to take

Comment: That's what the documentation is for

Comment: The dates are different. 20 translates to 26th Feb. Time travel, indeed!

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment Your username is ironic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String theInDate = "2/20/2016";

    String theInFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    String theOutFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy";

    final SimpleDateFormat theSdfInputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(theInFormat);
    final SimpleDateFormat theSdfOutputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(theOutFormat);

    final Date theDate = theSdfInputFormatter.parse(theInDate);

    final String theDateText = theSdfOutputFormatter.format(theDate);

    System.out.println(theDateText);

    }
}
```

You might wantto check the setLinient(true) functionality on the date parser as well.

And with the new Date API

```
    String theInDate = "2/20/2016";

    String theInFormat = "M/d/yyyy";
    String theOutFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy";

    final DateTimeFormatter theSdfInputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( theInFormat );
    final DateTimeFormatter theSdfOutputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(theOutFormat);

    final LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.from( theSdfInputFormatter.parse( theInDate ) );

    final String theDateText = theSdfOutputFormatter.format(theDate);

    System.out.println(theDateText);
```

Be aware of thread safety. take a look at the javadoc.
This solution works for Java. For Android, as tagged, it should be quite similar.
And even though this is a duplicate answer I hope it helps someone to solve an issue very fast and get an understanding how it works for further self study.

Comment: Answering obvious duplicate Questions is not helpful.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).